# How to make a haskell function that returns all matches of a specific regex?

Tags: regex, haskell

I find that I can do something like this the below with string literals

```
import Text.Regex.TDFA
import Text.Regex.TDFA ()

let x = ("foo" =~ ("o" :: String)) :: [[String]]
```

But I cannot at all figure out a way to do something like

`getMatches input = (input =~ "o") :: [[String]]`

it gives me something like

`Non type-variable argument in the constraint: RegexContext Text.Regex.TDFA.Text.Regex source1 [[String]]`

I have been googling for a long while and can't find anything that gives me the exact type signature I want.

Does anyone know if there is any way to do this?

Comment: Um, your proposed function compiles just fine, if you actually import `Text.Regex.TDFA`.

Comment: I now get Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: RegexContext
                             Text.Regex.TDFA.Text.Regex source1 [[String]]

Comment: Then you also get `(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)`. Why not try such tips yourself, before asking on StackOverflow?

Comment: I assumed it was bad practice. My apologies. Thank you for the quick help.

Comment: `import Text.Regex.TDFA ()` means load the module but don't import any definitions. You should remove this line, since `import Text.Regex.TDFA` already loaded the module and imported definitions. Perhaps you wanted to `import Text.Regex.TDFA ((=~))`, which would just load in the `(=~)` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way to make a Haskell function that returns all matches of a specific *text pattern*, then maybe [“try this instead”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) of regex.

With https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:splitCap

```
import Text.Megaparsec (chunk)
import Replace.Megaparsec (splitCap)
import Data.Either (rights)

rights $ splitCap (chunk "o") "foo"
```

```
["o","o"]
```